# Flutter Riverpod listen not being invoked

Tags: flutter, riverpod

I'm trying to implement just a basic listener in a widget (I will want to show a snackbar) but it just isnt being invoked by the provider. Cant see what Im doing wrong here.
I've tried from other widgets and the listener still doesn't hear the event.

Any ideas?

```
int foo = 1;
final FooProvider = Provider<int>((ref) {
  foo = foo + 1;
  return foo;
});

class showSnack extends ConsumerWidget {
  final int taskID;
  const showSnack(this.taskID);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context, WidgetRef ref) {
    ref.listen<int>(FooProvider, (int? previousCount, int newCount) {
      logger.d("Fooo event");
    });
    return TaskInfo(taskID);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The basic `Provider` is not a state-holding type of provider. It's basically a static provider of some sort of data or a service class, meaning that it can't be used to watch for state changes or for listening.

You should probably use the `StateProvider`, `StateNotifierProvider` or the `ChangeNotifierProvider`. You can read more about the different providers in [the documentation](https://riverpod.dev/docs/concepts/providers#different-types-of-providers).